# 'get_previous_post' in same category returning (!empty) when no previous post in category exists

Tags: posts, categories, navigation

I'm trying to use the Smarter Navigation plugin to work so that when I click on an individual post from the category page, the single post navigation only goes to the next post in the same category. I am using the plugin because the default WP navigation doesn't take into account the referring link when a post has multiple categories.

This is the code for the link to the previous post in `single.php`:

```
<?php 
    $prev_post = get_previous_post(TRUE,'all','category');
    if(!empty($prev_post)):
        echo 'not empty'; 
        previous_post_smart();
    else:
        echo 'empty';
    endif; 
?>
```

This is what is happening, taking into account these posts and category arrangements

Category-ALL:
4th-post, 3rd-post, 2nd-post, 1st-post,

Category-IMAGE:
4th-post, 2nd-post

Category-VIDEO:
3rd-post, 1st-post

With the above code in the `single.php` template for the 2nd-post, if I click on the link for the 2nd-post from the Category-IMAGE page, it will echo `not empty` but the `previous_post_smart()` function will return nothing because there is no previous post in the IMAGE category.

If I understand correctly `get_previous_post(TRUE,'all','category')` is saying, "get the previous post in the *same category* excluding the category *all*, but I think what is happening is that it is including the category *all*.

I say this because the same is true for the reverse; for the 3rd-post, referred from the Category-VIDEO page, with the `get_next_post()` function with the same parameters it also returns `(!empty)`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out :) It ends up the Smarter Navigation plugin has a few other functions that I missed:

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/smarter-navigation/trunk/template-tags.php

I used `get_adjacent_id_smart()` like so:

```
<?php
    $prev_post = get_adjacent_id_smart(true);
    if(!empty($prev_post)):
        echo 'not empty'; 
        previous_post_smart();
    else:
        echo 'empty';
    endif; 
?>
```

And I got the behavior I was looking for, don't know why the default WP function was not working according to the codex.